# Upload file over SFTP with Net::SFTP::Foreign

Tags: perl, sftp, net-sftp

I have a file `Test1.csv` on my local machine. I have a Perl script to copy this file to a remote location (`home/inbound`) through an SFTP connection.

Below is my code

```
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;

use warnings;
use strict;

my $host = "sftp.abcd.com";
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host, user => 'user10524', password => 'XXXX');
$sftp->error and die "Something bad happened: " . $sftp->error;

$sftp->put("Test1.csv", "/inbound") or die "put failed: " . $sftp->error;
```

But I am getting this error, when I run the program:

> put failed: Couldn't open remote file '/inbound': No such file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter of [`put`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign#$sftp-%3Eput($local,-$remote,-%opts)) is a path to the file, not a path to the target folder.

So it should be:

```
$sftp->put("Test1.csv", "/inbound/Test1.csv")
```